# case when date column is greater than sysdate then 'Y'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I created a case statement that checks a date in another column, and ends as an alias.

I need to create another case statement that will look at the new alias column and see if it's greater than the sysdate.  If so, then 'Y'.

Here is the current query:

```
select
  v.voyage "Voyage"
  ,v.service "Service"
  ,to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') "ETA"
  ,case 
    when v.service = "USA" then to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')
    else 'n/a'
    end as "Notice"
from 
  table
```

Produces the following results:

```
Voyage | Service | ETA   | Notice
_______________________________
test12 | USA     | 12/13 | 12/11
test14 | USA     | 12/15 | 12/13
```

I need to do something like this:

```
select
  v.voyage "Voyage"
  ,v.service "Service"
  ,to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') "ETA"
  ,case 
    when v.service = 'USA' then to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')
    else 'n/a'
    end as "Notice"
  ,case 
    when "Notice" > sysdate then 'Y' else 'N'
    end as "Sent"
from 
  table
```

Should produce the following:

```
Voyage | Service | ETA   | Notice | Sent
________________________________________
test12 | USA     | 12/13 | 12/11  | N
test14 | USA     | 12/15 | 12/13  | Y
```

But I am getting an error that reads:

```
a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

How can I fix this?

*** EDIT ***

I am getting the following error:

```
"Notice": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Do you have a column named USA? (Double quotes are for identifiers, and single quotes for string literals.)

Comment: My mistake.  I updated the question.

Comment: you need to edit the question and show the table DDL for all the referenced column, along with exact sample data.

Comment: You can't reference the result of one calculated column in another calculated column (which I think is what you are doing) as there is no guaranteed order in which the columns are calculated. You either need to replicate the 1st calculation in the 2nd calculated column or use something like a CTE to hold the 1st calculation

Comment: You are comparing a string (`Notice` column) to a date (`sysdate`). That's not going to work. You'll need something like `CASE WHEN v.service = 'USA' AND vp.eta_date - 2 > sysdate THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'` to pull this off. Or... don't cast your aliased columns to string if you want to do date comparison on them later down in the logic.

Comment: @ JNevill - that's exactly what I was looking for.  I did CASE WHEN v.service = 'USA' AND vp.eta_date - 2 > sysdate THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' and it worked.  If you post this answer, I will accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need *either* to copy the whole definition of the "Notice" column in the second `case` - which is not a best practice and it is not `DRY` (i.e. replicated same code)

```
  ,case 
    when /*"Notice"*/
     case 
     when v.service = 'USA' then to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')
     else 'n/a'
     end 
     > sysdate then 'Y' else 'N'
    end as "Sent"
```

or *better* use subquery  or `CTE`

```
with dt as (
select
  v.voyage "Voyage"
  ,v.service "Service"
  ,to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') "ETA"
  ,case 
    when v.service = 'USA' then to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')
    else 'n/a'
    end as "Notice"
from 
  table  
)
select dt.* ,
case 
    when "Notice" > sysdate then 'Y' else 'N'
    end as "Sent"
from dt
```

As pointed out in comment, this will enable you to *compile* (parse) the query, but is will **not return** the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for helping.  However, JNevill had the answer I was looking for.  Upvoted for helping.

Comment: 'n/a' > sysdate ?